# how to find time difference from row names?

Tags: r

I have a data frame object with row names that are time stamps. "SIZE" is the only variable so far.

```
                           SIZE
2008-01-14 09:29:49         0
2008-01-14 09:29:59         0
2008-01-14 09:29:59.1       0
2008-01-14 09:30:00        842
2008-01-14 09:30:00.1      34
2008-01-14 09:30:00.2       1
2008-01-14 09:30:00.3       1
2008-01-14 09:30:00.4       1
2008-01-14 09:30:00.5       1
2008-01-14 09:30:02        38
```

I would like to create a new column that shows the time difference from the previous row. The time difference from the first row can be blank.

```
                        SIZE  dtime
2008-01-14 09:29:49      0     NA
2008-01-14 09:29:59      0     10 
2008-01-14 09:29:59.1    0     0.1
2008-01-14 09:30:00    842     0.9
2008-01-14 09:30:00.1   34     0.1
2008-01-14 09:30:00.2    1     0.1
2008-01-14 09:30:00.3    1     0.1
2008-01-14 09:30:00.4    1     0.1
2008-01-14 09:30:00.5    1     0.1
2008-01-14 09:30:02     38     1.5
```

I am trying to use a loop to solve it like:

```
file<-as.data.frame(mtq)
L<-nrow(file)
file$dtime<-NA
for (f in 2:L){

  file$dtime[f]<-difftime(row.names(file)[f], row.names(file)[f-1])
}
```

It has a error of "replacement has 12853 rows, data has 12852"

Would anyone please give me some advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `diff` after converting to `POSIXct`.  The length of the `diff` output will be one less than than nrow of the dataset.  So, we can append `NA` at the beginning.

```
 df1$dtime <- c(NA,round(diff(as.POSIXct(row.names(df1))),1))
 df1
 #                      SIZE dtime
 #2008-01-14 09:29:49      0    NA
 #2008-01-14 09:29:59      0  10.0
 #2008-01-14 09:29:59.1    0   0.1
 #2008-01-14 09:30:00    842   0.9
 #2008-01-14 09:30:00.1   34   0.1
 #2008-01-14 09:30:00.2    1   0.1
 #2008-01-14 09:30:00.3    1   0.1
 #2008-01-14 09:30:00.4    1   0.1
 #2008-01-14 09:30:00.5    1   0.1
 #2008-01-14 09:30:02     38   1.5
```

Or

```
 v1 <- as.POSIXct(row.names(df1))
 df1$dtime <- round(v1-lag(v1),1)
```