# Creating a new column using ddply in the R package "plyr"

Tags: r, plyr

I am working on an animal tracking data set, and I need to calculate the time difference between time stamps for each GPS position for each individual.
For simplicity, my data looks like this (lets forget about the other variables for now):

```
ID  Time
B1  6:57
B1  6:59
B1  7:03
B1  7:10
B2  6:34
B2  6:45
B2  6:47
B2  6:48
B3  6:23
B3  6:35
B3  6:46
B3  6:47
```

I tried to calculate the time difference using the following:

```
ddply(df, "ID",transform,timediff=diff(Time))
```

However I get this error message:

> Error in data.frame(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Time = 8:11):
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3

I assume the problem is that there is no value for the first row for each Animal. Is there a way around this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try `c(NA, diff(Time))`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!!!
I tried 
`ddply(time, "Individual",transform,timediff=c(NA,diff(Time))`
But I get a "+", so I'm still missing something

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket.

Comment: oops! thank you both SO much! 
I'm new to R, and still have a lot of learning to do!

Comment: I would seriously consider using dplyr over plyr. It's the newer version, so more support going forward. And it has nice functions to do this like mutate()!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find time difference from row names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488617/how-to-find-time-difference-from-row-names)

Comment: You should use dplyr; plyr has been obsolete since 2013. dplyr is nicer syntax and more performant.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, because there are more than one animals.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)

# create a lag variable of time by ID
setDT(data)[, timediff:=c(NA, Time[-.N]), by=ID]

dt
#>     ID Time timediff
#>  1: B1 6:57       NA
#>  2: B1 6:59        8
#>  3: B1 7:03        9
#>  4: B1 7:10       10
#>  5: B2 6:34       NA
#>  6: B2 6:45        2
#>  7: B2 6:47        4
#>  8: B2 6:48        6
#>  9: B3 6:23       NA
#>  10: B3 6:35       1
#>  11: B3 6:46       3
#>  12: B3 6:47       5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
 df1$timediff <- with(df1, ave(as.numeric(Time), ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
```

assuming that 'Time' is of datetime class.